# Replacing false in excel if function with existing values in a table

Tags: excel

I am trying to use an if statement in excel to organize data gotten from GPS car tracker.

[image: car data]

```
=IF(B1="A 300 rd", "parking lot", "leave it as it is",IF(B1="A 600 rd", "Car wash", "leave as it is"))
```

I need the expression not to replace the data if the expression evaluates to false i.e. if false then "leave as it is".

Comment: "Leave it as it is" leave what as it is? Where is this formula going?

Comment: I mean that if the expression does not evaluate to true, then excel should leave the default column data without changing it

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(B1="A 300 rd", "parking lot",IF(B1="A 600 rd", "Car wash", B1))
```

Comment: Thnks but it evaluates to zero if false

Comment: Make sure you are changing the cell references to the correct row.  If you are entering this formula into row 2, then each instance of B1 needs to be B2.

Comment: Still evaluating to zero.

Comment: Are you entering the formula into cell C2? The first row is a table header by the looks of things.